# What do 5 star restaurants do differently when cooking steak?

Tags: steak

Recently I had an $80 steak, and it was the best thing I have ever eaten. I do not normally eat this sort of pricey food and so I was shocked at just how good it tasted. My question then, what exactly do chefs at these top restaurants do with their steaks to make it so tasty. Are the raw ingredients better? Is it preparation or cooking mechanism? Some strange technique? I just don't see how the raw steaks I buy and cook myself could ever be made to taste so good. It didn't even taste like the same meat. And it wasn't topped our coated in much, just peppercorn. I didn't even need steak sauce it was so tender.

Comment: An $80 steak is likely USDA Prime, which you generally cannot get in the grocery store. Prime beef has good eating characteristics including marbling of lots of fat.